# Save array of objects in state - ReactJS

Tags: arrays, object, reactjs, state

I am building a ReactJS application, and I need to store data in this way:

```
this.state = {
    user: {
        name: "",
        surname: "",
        age: "",
        ...
        instruments: [],
    }
}
```

The `instruments` state needs to contain several objects, with properties `name` and `experience`. An example:

```
instruments: [
    {
        name: 'Bass guitar',
        experience: 7,
    },
    {
        name: 'Drums',
        experience: 1,
    }
    ...
]
```

I'm new to React, so far I have been able to save data in similar arrays by doing this:

```
musicListenChange(val){
        let musicListenArray = this.state.user.music_listen ? this.state.user.music_listen : [];
        musicListenArray.push(val.value);
        this.setState({user: {...this.state.user, music_listen: musicListenArray}});
    }
```

However, when I try to save an object with the following code I receive an error:

```
saveInstrument(){
        // save current instruments state in array, or create an empty one 
        let array = this.state.user.instruments ? this.state.user.instruments : [];

        // in this.state.instruments I saved a temporary copy of the selected instrument, put it in the array
        array.push(this.state.instruments);
        this.setState({user: {...this.state.user, instruments: array }});
        console.log('instrum. state: ', this.state.user.instruments);
    }
```

**Error code**

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, experience}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `EditProfile`.
```

**My EditProfile render part for the instruments**

```
<div className="container-tags">
    {this.state.user.instruments ? this.state.user.instruments.map(function (instrument, index) {
        return <button className="btn btn-default">{instrument}</button>;
    }) : <div></div>}
</div>
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: what do you have inside `this.state.instruments`?

Comment: Inside this.state.instruments I save {name: "string", experience:"string"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instrument is an object, and you are trying to render it, use the specific value that you wants to render, Try this:

```
musicListenChange(val){
    let user = this.state.user;  
    user['music_listen'] = val.value;
    this.setState({user: user);
}

saveInstrument(){
    let user = this.state.user;
    user['instruments'] = user['instruments'] ? user['instruments'] : [];
    user['instruments'].push(this.state.instruments);
    this.setState({user: user});
}
```

In render function use this:

```
{this.state.user.instruments ? 
     this.state.user.instruments.map((instrument, index) => {
        return (<button className="btn btn-default">{instrument.name}</button>)
     })
:<div/>
}
```

Comment: this.state.instruments is not an array actually, it's an object. So I think the problem is not there.. but thanks for trying

Comment: if this.state.instrument is an object then how u r using {instrument} in html, how you are printing an object.

Comment: i did some changes, plz check.

Comment: @TheCondor You must be confused, `this.state.instruments` is definitely an array since you define it like `instruments: []` and then do array operations on it, such as `push` or `map`. It's an array of objects.

Comment: I would say that this is considered a bad practice. A new object for `user` must be recreated each time state changes with `setState()`, e.g. `const user = { ...this.state.user }` before changing `user`, then you can make changes to `user` and finally call `setState({user})`. This way you allow your state to work with pure components too, otherwise they won't rerender.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
<div className="container-tags">
    {this.state.user.instruments ? this.state.user.instruments.map(function (instrument, index) {
        return <button className="btn btn-default">{instrument}</button>;
    }) : <div></div>}
</div>
```

When realising that `instrument` is a JavaScript object (you said that your `instruments` array contains objects with structure `{name: "string", experience:"string"}`), the error message becomes clear: you are trying to insert an object as a child of the `<button>` element, which is not allowed, since React has no idea how to display an object. If you used `instrument.name` or `instrument.experience` instead (which are strings), your code will work.

Comment: Perfect, this was the problem! But the other user replied before and suggested the same solution, therefore I gave the right answer to him. Thanks!